# Why is naive multiplication n^2 time?

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, multiplication

I've read that operations such as addition/subtraction were linear time, and that "grade-school" long multiplication is n^2 time. Why is this true?

Isn't addition `floor(log n)` times, when n is the smaller operand? The same argument goes for subtraction, and for multiplication, if we make a program to do long multiplication instead of adding integers together, shouldn't the complexity be `floor(log a) * floor(log b)` where a and b are the operands?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer depends on what is "n." When they say that addition is O(n) and multiplication (with the naïve algorithm) is O(n^2), n is the length of the number, either in bits or some other unit. This definition is used because arbitrary precision arithmetic is implemented as operations on lists of "digits" (not necessarily base 10).

If n is the number being added or multiplied, the complexities would be log n and (log n)^2 for positive n, as long as the numbers are stored in log n space.

Answer (score 2):

The naive approach to multiplication of (for example) `273 x 12` is expanded out (using the distributive rule) as `(200 + 70 + 3) x (10 + 2)` or:

```
  200 x 10 + 200 x  2 
+  70 x 10 +  70 x  2
+   3 x 10 +   3 x  2
```

The idea of this simplification is to reduce the multiplications to something that can be done easily. For your primary school math, that would be working with digits, assuming you know the times tables from zero to nine. For bignum libraries where each "digit" may be a value from 0 to 9999 (for ease of decimal printing), the same rules apply, being able to multiply numbers less than 10,000 relatively constantly).

Hence, if `n` is the number of digits, the complexity is indeed `O(n2)` since the number of "constant" operations tends to rise with the product of the "digit" counts.

This is true even if your definition of digit varies slightly (such as being a value from 0 to 9999 or even being one of the binary digits `0` or `1`).

Comment: What is n here? 3? 5? I only see a total of 6 multiplications. How is that n^2?

Comment: @awgtek: don't confuse complexity with metrics:-) Complexity can be thought of as a measure of how complex something becomes as the input variable approaches some sufficiently large value (like infinite), not a specific result for a given `n`. In this case, you can think of it as the number of digits in the numbers, as they *both* increase. Since you have to multiply each digit in one by each digit in the other, the number of multiplications is effectively the two digit counts multiplied together. The reason you get six is because we multiply three digits by two, but that's not complexity.

Comment: In other words, two 10-digit numbers would be 100 operations, two 100-digit numbers would be 10,000 ops, and so on. The operation count tends to rise with the square of the digit count in both numbers. Obviously, that's not the case if one of the numbers is always a single digit, but complexity analysis deals with the limit, not a specific scenario.

Comment: Ok, I see, this is because of the number of final additions needed in the partial products method, so assuming worse case case n is 3 (largest of the two), then 9 total additions is required. That's how I understand where the n^2 comes from...